# Beginner learning Python (and programming) fundamentals. I'm struggling to understand and utilize Python libraries

Tags: python, pycharm, package, libraries, python-module

Apologies for the vagueness of the title and the question as well, I simply have a lot of questions and am looking for a rundown or resources to help me. I've been through relevant Python documentation and taken Google as far as I can, but I need some general explanation.

What are the differences between libraries, packages, and modules? Are default Python modules/libraries that come with the language different inherently from ones you can install? Where are these libraries stored? I've heard a lot about using pip and tried it with varying amounts of success for varying libraries. It's also worth noting I currently use PyCharm as my IDE. How does this change my use of libraries? Where does pip install libraries to? What does the file hierarchy look like for these libraries, and Python projects as a whole? How is the different with an IDE like PyCharm? What exactly is a virtual environment and how is it different from what I assume to be a Python environment you use in a regular text editor? I've read some about them and it appears you can install libraries to only the environment? Where are these installed to?

Obviously I don't want bulleted answers to each of these questions individually, I'm just seeking an understanding. I can sum up my mess of a "question" by asking: How do these elements like libraries, my IDE, pip, the venv, the language itself, and actual files on my computer interact?

Now that I have a basic understanding of the syntax of the language, it feels necessary to understand these fundamentals to develop actual projects of any kind. Any insight whatsoever is appreciated, especially given the fragmented nature of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your IDE will call some commands for you:

- creating virtualenv when you create a new project: `python -m venv venv_dir`
- install packages when you click the plus sign in IDE: `pip install package`
- might set PYTHONPATH variable, which tells python where to look for imported packages besides libraries in site-packages

You can always check where python looks for installed packages with:

```
>>> import site
>>> site.getsitepackages()
['/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages']
```

Or where did pip install your package:

```
pip show package_name

pip3 show requests
...
Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

python looks for libraries relative to it's location on the filesystem. This fact is used to create a separate directory for installed packages, and it's called virtualenv.

```
cd venv
tree -L 4
.
├── bin
│   ├── activate
│   ├── activate.csh
│   ├── activate.fish
│   ├── easy_install
│   ├── easy_install-3.6
│   ├── pip
│   ├── pip3
│   ├── pip3.6
│   ├── python -> python3
│   └── python3 -> /usr/bin/python3
├── include
├── lib
│   └── python3.6
│       └── site-packages
│           ├── __pycache__
│           ├── easy_install.py
│           ├── pip
│           ├── pip-9.0.1.dist-info
│           ├── pkg_resources
│           ├── pkg_resources-0.0.0.dist-info
│           ├── setuptools
│           └── setuptools-39.0.1.dist-info
```

See how python is just a symlink to system python, but it has a separate `site-packages` directory.